# Postgresql в rails проекте

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь сделать деплой приложения на Heroku. Для этого заменил бд с sqlite3 на postgresql, однако при вводе команды bin/rails db:create консоль выдает следующее:
We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml.

To resolve this issue:

- Did you create the database for this app, or delete it? You may need to create your database.
- Has the database name changed? Check your database.yml config has the correct database name.

To create your database, run:

```
    bin/rails db:create
```

Couldn't create 'twitter_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: We could not find your database: postgres. Which can be found in the database configuration file located at config/database.yml.

To resolve this issue:

- Did you create the database for this app, or delete it? You may need to create your database.
- Has the database name changed? Check your database.yml config has the correct database name.

To create your database, run:

```
    bin/rails db:create
```

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: ВАЖНО:  роль "arseny" не существует

В Gemfile есть gem 'pg' и я полностью убрал sqlite3 (хотя его наличие ни на что не влияло). В gemfile.lock также нет упоминаний  sqlite3

database.yml:

default: &default

adapter: postgresql

encoding: unicode

pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
<<: *default
database: twitter_development

test:
<<: *default
database: twitter_test

production:
<<: *default

database: twitter_production

username: twitter_app

password: <%= ENV['TWITTER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

host: localhost
port: 5432

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `bin/rails db:create` вы где выполняете? На хероку или локально?

Comment: выполняю локально

Comment: при выполнении на хероку ничего не происходит

Comment: Постгрес при этом стоит локально, простите за идиотский вопрос? Не гем, а сама база, я имею в виду. Для дев окружения в database.yml не хватает host, user и password

Comment: Да, постгрес установлен локально